# Is Mark V. Shaney still the best way to generate text?

Tags: nlp

I want to take large documents and generate text that resembles them. I know that Markov Chains were used to do this with [Mark V Shaney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_V_Shaney). Is there a better way to do it now, or is this approach still basically the best one available?

Comment: I dont know about your answer but this mark v shaney thing is awesome. Found the python code and started jumbling up websites about wolves. http://www.strout.net/info/coding/python/shaney.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether Markov Chains are the best way of generating text but that's surely an easy way.

There is an alternative way in [deep linguistic processin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linguistic_processing)g using semantic to grammatical generators such as the [ACE Parser/Generator](http://sweaglesw.org/linguistics/ace/). Maybe you can test the generation power of deep grammar through [their demo site](http://erg.delph-in.net/logon). After you parse a sentence on the demo site, there is an option to generate similar sentences.